# Entries Overview: Add Field Columns

Tags: entries, control-panel, cp-dashboard

Does anyone have an idea how I can add columns in the entries overview? Columns with the title of the fields that exist in the page and are filled with content. [image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the columns to display using the little cogwheel icon at the bottom (below the list of sections):

[image: Cogwheel icon at the bottom of the section list]

This will open a modal window allowing you to select the fields you want to display in the table for each section. You can also rearrange the fields using drag-and-drop with the little handle icon to the left of the field name.

As a sidenote, this modal also allows you to reorder the sections in the sidebar, and use your own headings instead of the default headings for channels and structures.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I didn't realise that I could change it like that. Thank you. 
But fields created by me are not displayed there - so I can only take the "standard selection" from Craft?

Comment: @ChuckLean Custom fields should be available, at least they are in my development environment. Based on some quick testing, I think if you have a section with multiple entry types, the available columns will be limited to the fields that are common to all entry types. Not sure though, other limitations might apply.

Comment: Allright, I'll have to try that out then. Thank you very much for your help.